# Ubuntu 18.04 dual-boot - windows 10 upgrade has trashed uefi boot entries

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

These 2 systems have co-existed since late 2014 (Windows was 8 back then, ubuntu can't remember 14?)

Unfortunately, the latest window update appears to have trashed the boot loader - the computer boots straight into Windows, when I "advanced restart" and go into the BIOS the ubuntu partitions can no longer be seen.

I can see them if i use bcdedit in windows, and a Ubuntu install usb also finds them.

How can I restore the boot loader to its former glory? I think it was grub2 - it's whatever the default was back in 2014

Comment: I found this answer from 2016, which means I can now manually boot into ubuntu at startup https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/682462 but I'm now struggling to get this process to be automatic

Comment: Both Windows & Ubuntu/grub have always updated boot loader to make them first or default with major updates. With UEFI, you should be able to boot either install from UEFI boot menu. Most systems, let you use efibootmgr from live installer to reset boot order. But it seems everyone with HP has posted they can only change boot order from within UEFI settings as you have done.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this answer got grub reinstalled on my system:

https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/682462

Then, on my HP laptop, I had to boot into: `BIOS Setup`

From here I chose: `System configuration -> Boot options -> UEFI Boot order -> OS Boot Manager`

And in here I moved the entry called `ubuntu something` above Windows.

Then `F10` to save & exit boot order.

One more `F10` to save the BIOS and exit.

Now I get the boot Grub menu on startup, and if I do nothing, the laptop boots into my Linux. Phew!

There isn't a way to prevent Windows from doing this ever again? (Other than delete the whole thing, which I may well do)